# make element preview by type of file e.g [img,video,audio]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

i'm build a web-app chat and i make a upload system on it,
first i make a image `input[type="file"]`
then a record button `[upload as wav]`

example:

[image]

anyway i I am viewing files with `if(condition)` ,

example :

```
         if (data.file == 'audio') {
            $('<audio style="display:block;width:250px;" controls src="' + data.message + '"></audio>').appendTo($('.messages ul'));
        }else if (data.file == 'image'){
            $(''<img class="imageChat"   ' +
                'src="' + filterXSS(data.message) + '"' +
                'href="' + filterXSS(data.message) + '"' + '>'
                +).appendTo($('.messages ul'));

        }
```

but  what i need is to AUTO-detect file type and create the element based on the type of it ?

### Update:

example:

```
showFile('assets/this-is-img.php?a=b') // will return an $('img') element
```

i know how to get the file type but i need to pass the file type to script and it will return the preview element like img for photos , iframe for PDFs,audio for audios,`etc`

is this possible? 
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could make a decision based on the file extension of the uploaded file.

Comment: @obscure , thanks for replay  ,, first some files not have a EXT , also i need to detect it automatically

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "auto-detect". I'm not aware of a way to do this with a URL, yet you could look for extensions in the URL like `.htm`, `.jpg`, `.mp4`

Comment: @Twisty ,, i do more explain , i hope you get my idea , it's not about file type it's about the element i will preview the file on it

Comment: @A.El-zahaby Still does not make sense. Ultimately, you will need a function that will conditionally be able to make a decision about the `type` of file and create a object based on a template. Please provide a more complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example. The core function here is `makeElement()`, it takes some basic data passed to it as a object and create a jQuery Object based on the HTML Element.

The heavy lifting is done by `fileToElem()` which takes some info about the files and can based on the type of file take some conditional actions. If it sees a specific file and has a data template for it.

```js
$(function() {
  var files = [{
      file: "audio",
      message: "assets/this-is-img.php?a=b"
    },
    {
      file: "image",
      message: "assets/this-is-img.php?a=b"
    }
  ];

  function makeElement(d, t) {
    var el = $("<" + d.nodeName + ">", d.attr).prop(d.prop);
    if (t != undefined) {
      el.appendTo(t);
    }
    return el;
  }

  function fileToElem(data, target) {
    var item;
    switch (data.file) {
      case "audio":
        item = makeElement({
          nodeName: "audio",
          attr: {
            class: "audioChat",
            style: "display:block;width:250px;",
            src: data.message
          },
          prop: {
            controls: true
          }
        }, target);
        break;
      case "image":
        item = makeElement({
          nodeName: "img",
          attr: {
            class: "imageChat",
            src: data.message
          },
          prop: {}
        }, target);
        break;
      case "video":
        item = makeElement({
          nodeName: "video",
          attr: {
            class: "videoChat",
            src: data.message
          },
          prop: {
            controls: true
          }
        }, target);
        break;
      case "pdf":
        item = makeElement({
          nodeName: "a",
          attr: {
            class: "pdfChat",
            href: data.message,
            target: "_BLANK"
          },
          prop: {}
        }, target);
        break;
    }
    // Do other things with 'item' if needed here
  }

  $.each(files, function(i, data) {
    var listItem = $("<li>").data("date", new Date().toString()).appendTo($(".messages ul"));
    fileToElem(data, listItem);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

You can keep adding more conditions to your `switch()` based on the file types you expect. If you're not familar with `switch()` it's a complex if handler.

> The `switch` statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a `case` clause, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case.

See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user can only upload one file at a time, you can get the `filelist` from the input[type=file] `document.getElementById("Id of the input").files[0]`. It returns a file object which has a type property. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for replay  ,, i do more explain on the post #update  , i hope you get my idea , it's not about file type it's about the element i will preview the file on it

Comment: If you're getting data using ajax. You can check the content-type header. I don't know any other way of doing it.